# Android Google Map Utils - Filtering Clusters

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I have an app I'm currently working on where I map out various Point of Interest on a Map. There are 5 different types of POI's and I've added the ability to filter out by type. I was able to properly implement the clustering of markers, and I also implemented filtering of individual markers by type without any issues, but I cannot figure out how to filter the markers included in a Cluster by type and then get the utility to redraw it's clusters.

For filtering the Markers by type, I created my own CustomClusterRenderer and did an override of the onClusterItemRendered:

```
@Override
protected void onClusterItemRendered(AbstractPOI clusterItem, Marker marker) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onClusterItemRendered(clusterItem, marker);

    if (mClusterManager.getMarkerMap().get(clusterItem.getPosition()) == null) {
        /*
         * Save a reference to the appropriate filter array by type. 
         */
        if (MapUtils.TYPE_HOTEL.equals(marker.getSnippet())) {
            mClusterManager.getHotelMarkers().add(marker);
        } else if (MapUtils.TYPE_PARK.equals(marker.getSnippet())) {
            mClusterManager.getParkMarkers().add(marker);
        } else if (MapUtils.TYPE_PROVIDER.equals(marker.getSnippet())) {
            mClusterManager.getProviderMarkers().add(marker);
        } else if (MapUtils.TYPE_RESTAURANT.equals(marker.getSnippet())) {
            mClusterManager.getRestaurantMarkers().add(marker);
        }

        /*
         * Save this marker to our marker map to prevent duplicates. 
         */
        mClusterManager.getMarkerMap().put(clusterItem.getPosition(), marker);
    }
}
```

This may end up being problematic if somehow it also means that the markers aren't included in clusters created during zooming. I'm not sure. This method above keeps references to the markers so that in my CustomClusterManager I can include functions for looping over these markers and setting their 'visible' property:

```
public void toggleHotelFilter(boolean visible) {
    for (Marker marker : mHotelMarkers) {
        marker.setVisible(visible);
    }
    cluster();
}
```

There may be a better way to do this, but so far, it does seem to work. The next part would be to get the filter to also dip into the Clusters and yank out the POI's that are being filtered, as well as update the count (or remove the cluster altogether depending on how much will be invisible).

**I am using the google-maps-utils library**